# PayPal Save for Purchase Later - Save cards issue

Tags: javascript, c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am creating a section on the checkout payment info where a customer should enter their card details so, in the case of market loss (*),  we can charge him later on that card through PayPal.
I am implementing this using the PayPal SDK for saving cPayPalards and charging later and I am having an issue with "createVaultSetupToken" callback. I created both the frontend and backend logic with a call to my backend to create a setup token and to PayPal API (FE code below, BE API request is just like in documentation paymnet_source with an empty card object).

```
createVaultSetupToken: async (data) => {
     const result = await fetch("/PayPalExtended/setup/token", { method: "POST" })
              var jsonRes = await result.json()
              const { id } = jsonRes;
              return id;
            },
```

This is successful with 201 Created and I get the token back I return it to the callback, and the SDK never calls OnApprove callback because I receive an error from PayPal SDK.

```
graphql_UpdateVaultSetupToken_error 
Object { err: "Cannot get vault - no customer id found in id token", timestamp: "1703524904796", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", sdkCorrelationID: "f137663e5663e", sessionID: "sessionID", clientID: "clientID", env: "sandbox" }
card-field:40:65202
```

OnError callback logs this:

```
Something went wrong: Error: Cannot get vault - no customer id found in id token
 https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/card-field?type=cvv&clientID=clientID&sessionID=sessionID&clientMetadataID=uid_a55f4eb2d9_mtc6mdm6ntu&cardFieldsSessionID=cardFieldsSessionID&env=sandbox&debug=false&locale.country=GB&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVFIR2Vna3lsX2RjRmdnVmoxODFOZG80cG5id3U1YmhwaFRyRFRKWXVpdXBHZlE2RVVvaWtWQjV3WTRJMXZzTi1VeldFVVFTNU5ubnVsNWgmY3VycmVuY3k9VVNEJmludGVudD1hdXRob3JpemUmY29tbWl0PWZhbHNlJnZhdWx0PXRydWUmZGVidWc9ZmFsc2UmY29tcG9uZW50cz1idXR0b25zLGNhcmQtZmllbGRzIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS1wYXJ0bmVyLWF0dHJpYnV0aW9uLWlkIjoiTm9wQ29tbWVyY2VfUFBDUCIsImRhdGEtdWlkIjoidWlkX3pqdnRodHZsZmFxaW9udGdhcGxyeHl1bnpsemp6cyJ9fQ&disable-card=&currency=USD&intent=authorize&commit=false&vault=true&sdkCorrelationID=f137663e5663e:40
```

Card I used is from Card testing page for advanced checkout :

```
Number: 2223000048400011

date: 11/25

CCV:123

Name:  Mark Thomas
```

Response from API/my backend:

```
{
  "jsonRes ": {
    "id": "2DV308********",
    "payment_source": {
      "Card": null,
      "Token": null
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": "uCEH******"
    },
    "status": "CREATED"
  }
}
```

PayPal script src:

```
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=clientId&amp;currency=USD&amp;intent=authorize&amp;commit=false&amp;vault=true&amp;debug=false&amp;components=buttons,card-fields" data-partner-attribution-id="NopCommerce_PPCP" data-page-type="checkout" data-user-id-token="data-user-id"
```

No idea what is the issue, tried almost everything :) .

* Since this is a Wire payment method, it can fail or a customer can blackout the trade after some time, and we have this policy where if this happens we charge the customer for the money lost on their credit card.

Tried almost everything.

- With hardcoded card details (thought empty card was the problem)
- adding billing address with card (thought missing address was the problem for customer)
- tried different cards, names, expiry dates, ccv..
- changing paypal script src query paramaters

Comment: `return id;` what is the value of `id` before this

Comment: The data i get from the PayPal API I pass to through my controller action to the FE, its value is in the "Response from API/my backend:" section above.

Comment: asked about the specific value at that specific moment in the code, not that object

Comment: I debugged and logged the ID value before returning it and it's the same as in the JSON object response.
"id": "2DV308********"

Comment: What is your backend's actual request and response to the API? Does it look like https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/purchase-later/js-sdk/cards/#link-backendsample ?

Comment: The other thing to attempt with is the simpler JS SDK string given there: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/purchase-later/js-sdk/cards/#link-addsdktohtmlpage , adding on to it further only if necessary (not all the things in your question's script src)

Comment: Yea the object i am sending is a payment source with an empty card body, and i receive data that i have above in "Response from API/my backend:" section.
I didn't try with a simpler body of a script, i will try that and follow up if anything changed.

Comment: I tried with a simpler JS JSK and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer, this script src and additional HTML tag attributes:

> src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=clientId&currency=USD&intent=authorize&commit=false&vault=true&debug=false&components=buttons,card-fields" data-partner-attribution-id="NopCommerce_PPCP" data-page-type="checkout" data-user-id-token="data-user-id"

Has too many extraneous things. In particular the data-user-id-token makes me suspicious there, but the intent might also be a problem for vault. In any case, seems the [shorter SDK src from the documentation for Save Payment Methods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/purchase-later/js-sdk/cards/#link-addsdktohtmlpage) will work:

> https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=card-fields&client-id=CLIENT-ID